# Reduce line spacing in Simple-CV template

Tags: cv

I'm using [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/simple-cv/wmsyrgqwwqnc) CV template from Overleaf. I'd like to reduce the spacing in the "experience" and " education" sections, particularly in the spaces marked with red the image.
[image]

I'd really appreciate if you could help me, as I've tried looking in this site, and could not find anything regarding this particular cv template, which is different from others that have been treated in the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to do it manually and a bit hardcoding try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
 
\begin{document}
example:\\
\vspace{1.5cm}
some text\\
some text\\
some text\\
some text\\[-1cm]
some text\\[1cm]
some text

\end{document}
```

[image]